# Selenium, Change browser from Chrome to Edge

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So I currently have code that works using chrome and webdrivermanager. However I was wondering if it is possible to convert the browser that Selenium uses from Chrome to Edge?

Is it as simple as a single line of code (redefining "driver" variable)? Or do I have to rewrite things completely?

The language is Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install Microsoft Edge WebDriver (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

After that, you can use it like this :

```
driver = webdriver.Edge(r"path/msedgedriver.exe")
```